# How to show specific text if one specific checkbox is checked among bunch of unique checkboxes

Tags: javascript, checkbox, unique, event-listener

I have a specific task to do, and I'm not sure what is the best way to do it.

I have around 60 unique checkboxes and when clicked, display some text on their right side (tied to that clicked checkbox).

I have done it with 64 specific `eventListeners`, but I'm not sure that this is the best way: I would like to simplify the code.

So, for example, I have bunch of checkboxes in a label that is: `test`, `test1`, `test2` and so on. And when I click on `test` checkbox, that the text: "hello world" can appear, if `test1` is checked, text: "One 2 three" can appear, if `test2` is checked, text: "I've done it" can appear, but if none of them is selected, texts will not be displayed.

This is the code, one event listener I have now:

```
var forSale = document.querySelector('#for_sale');
var forSaleEmail = document.querySelector('#for_sale_email');
/*For Sale*/
forSale.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(forSale.checked === true){
        forSaleEmail.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        forSaleEmail.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

Where the `forSale` variable is a checkbox and `forSaleEmail` is a text that should be displayed.

If you have any suggestions or you can tell me what to look for, it would be greatly appreciated.

HTML Code is as following:

```
<div><label>For Sale <input type="checkbox" id="for_sale"></label></div>
<div><span id="for_sale_email">
<p>
for sale
</p>
</span></div>
```

Comment: Can you post a section of the HTML?

Comment: Of course: 

    <label>For Sale <input type="checkbox" id="for_sale"></label>
    <span id="for_sale_email">
    <p>
    This is for sale                                
    </p>
    </span>

Comment: Perhaps add your html code in the question :)

Comment: More of the HTML, not just one

Comment: Sorry, added by mistake, all in top question :).

Answer (score 2):

An option is event delegation, where you add **one** event handler to a parent/ancestor of all the `input`'s, and use the event property `event.target` to detect the one that were clicked on, and simply toggle a class on its parents `div`.

Combined with the [CSS adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) `+` it gets as simple as this

*Note 1: Having a `<p>` inside an inline element like a `<span>` is not valid markup, so I removed it. If you need an extra, use another `<span>` and give it similar style a `<p>` has as default.*

*Note 2: `id` needs to be unique so make sure you have that taken care of, and for your `for_sale_email` it doesn't need to be, so I changed it to a class.*

*Note 3: If you want to "toggle" between the chosen `input`'s, I also added a code part that does that.*

Stack snippet

```js
document.querySelector('.inputs_parent').addEventListener('change', function(event) {

  // this will "hide" previous checked input
  var prev = this.querySelector('div.checked');
  if (prev) {
      prev.classList.remove('checked');
      prev.querySelector('input').checked = false;
  }


  // remove this "if" statement if won't use the above 
  if (!prev || !prev.contains(event.target))
      event.target.closest('div').classList.toggle('checked');

})
```

```css
.for_sale_email {
  display: none;
}

div.checked + div .for_sale_email {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputs_parent">

  <div>
    <label>For Sale
      <input type="checkbox" id="for_sale1">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="for_sale_email">
      for sale
    </span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>For Sale
      <input type="checkbox" id="for_sale2">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="for_sale_email">
      for sale
    </span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>For Sale
      <input type="checkbox" id="for_sale3">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="for_sale_email">
      for sale
    </span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>For Sale
      <input type="checkbox" id="for_sale4">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="for_sale_email">
      for sale
    </span>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

If you can make a small markup change, you can actually accomplish this with CSS alone.

Stack snippet

```css
.inputs_parent label:after {
  content: 'X';
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;  
  font-size: 12px;
  color: transparent;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.inputs_parent input,
.inputs_parent .for_sale_email {
  display: none;
}

.inputs_parent input:checked + div label:after {
  color: black;
}

.inputs_parent input:checked + div + div .for_sale_email {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputs_parent">

  <input type="checkbox" id="for_sale1">
  <div>
    <label for="for_sale1">For Sale
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="for_sale_email">
      for sale
    </span>
  </div>

  <input type="checkbox" id="for_sale2">
  <div>
    <label for="for_sale2">For Sale
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="for_sale_email">
      for sale
    </span>
  </div>

  <input type="checkbox" id="for_sale3">
  <div>
    <label for="for_sale3">For Sale
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="for_sale_email">
      for sale
    </span>
  </div>

  <input type="checkbox" id="for_sale4">
  <div>
    <label for="for_sale4">For Sale
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="for_sale_email">
      for sale
    </span>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

And this one toggle's the checked items, using an `input type="radio"`.

Stack snippet

```css
.inputs_parent label:after {
  content: 'X';
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;  
  font-size: 12px;
  color: transparent;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.inputs_parent input,
.inputs_parent .for_sale_email {
  display: none;
}

.inputs_parent input:checked + div label:after {
  color: black;
}

.inputs_parent input:checked + div + div .for_sale_email {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputs_parent">

  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="for_sale1">
  <div>
    <label for="for_sale1">For Sale
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="for_sale_email">
      for sale
    </span>
  </div>

  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="for_sale2">
  <div>
    <label for="for_sale2">For Sale
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="for_sale_email">
      for sale
    </span>
  </div>

  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="for_sale3">
  <div>
    <label for="for_sale3">For Sale
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="for_sale_email">
      for sale
    </span>
  </div>

  <input type="radio" name="radio" id="for_sale4">
  <div>
    <label for="for_sale4">For Sale
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="for_sale_email">
      for sale
    </span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: The thing is that they have to be under two specific <div>s

Comment: @GoranSovilj Then please edit that into your question, so we can see how it should look like, and I will be able to adjust my answer, as if you can avoid all that javascript you should

Comment: @GoranSovilj I will add a script sample to, using 1 event listener

Comment: @GoranSovilj  As the updated code sample of yours can't use CSS, I deleted that part and updated the script sample with your updated code

Comment: @GoranSovilj Updated again, added 2 versions using CSS alone (if a minor markup change is possible)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is totally fine, but you should definetly abstract it into a function:

```
function selectMessage(checkbockSelector, messageSelector) {
   var checkbox = document.querySelector(checkboxSelector);
   var message = document.querySelector(messageSelector);

   checkbox.addEventListener("click", function(){
      message.style.display = checkbox.selected ?  'block' : 'none';
   });
}
```

So that you can just do:

```
selectMessage("#for_sale", "#for_sale_email");
```

---

If there are a lot of elements, it might be a good idea to change the HTML into a structure, that directly relates the labels with the input:

```
<div id="sale">
  <label>For Sale</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="for_sale" class="withhint">
  <span class="hint">
    <p>for sale</p>
  </span>   
</div>
```

Then you can hide them with CSS by default:

```
.hint { display: none; }
```

And use javascript to apply the handler to all:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".withhint").forEach(function(input) {
  const hint = input.parentElement.querySelector(".hint");
  input.addEventListener("click", function() {
     hint.style.display = input.checked ? "block" : "none";
  });
});
```

[Try it!](http://jsbin.com/mefevusifa/edit?output)

Comment: So, i have around 64 unique checkboxes with 64 unique texts. How can i implement this on a higher scale? This is perfect, as i can see, not so complicated :).

Comment: @goran added another way

Comment: Haha, i'm an idiot. Forgot to add that label and span tag should be separated. i edited my question to show you. THANK YOU SO MUCH.